# Apple wallet- Pass not getting updated

Tags: php, ios, .net, swift, apple-wallet

I am able to add pass received from server to Apple wallet but not getting why pass not getting updated. So, my queries as an iOS developer are:

1. Who will create pass if it needs to be updated from backend automatically without my iOS app interaction
2. What is the role of my iOS app in handling pass(adding updating data in Apple Wallet)
3. Who will register for push notifications after pass added to wallet and who will get push token
4. At whose end backend or app end this api will be called

   [https://yourpasshost.example.com/v1/devices/{deviceLibraryIdentifier}/registrations/{passTypeIdentifier}/{serialNumber}](https://yourpasshost.example.com/v1/devices/%7BdeviceLibraryIdentifier%7D/registrations/%7BpassTypeIdentifier%7D/%7BserialNumber%7D)

Below is my code for adding pass to wallet:

```
 let passURL = URL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iospasswallet.appspot.com/o/pass1.pkpass?alt=media&token=397cb8-d939-4241-b8f8-a1f7e4f8d937")!

    // Use URLSession to download pass data asynchronously
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: passURL) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error downloading pass data: \(error)")
            return
        }
        
        guard let passData = data else {
            print("Failed to get pass data")
            return
        }

        do {
            let pass = try PKPass(data: passData)
            let passLibrary = PKPassLibrary()
            passLibrary.addPasses([pass]) { (status) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if status.rawValue == 0 {
                        print("Pass added successfully")
                    } else if status.rawValue == 1 {
                        print("Pass review successfully")
                    } else {
                        print("Cancelled Status: \(status.rawValue)")
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error creating pass: \(error)")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *You* have to create the pass if you want to be able to update it.
2. Your app doesn't have much to do - just getting a pass (maybe from sone internal API of yours), and handing it over to the system.
3. The act of adding a pass automatically registers the device for push notifications, and the registration callback you'll receive will contain a push token to allow you to do that.
4. In that example, `yourpasshost.example.com` is most likely the same server that you got the pass from, i.e. yours.

One key thing to realise is that once a pass is installed, it's independent of *how* it was installed, and *all* of your interaction with it from that point occurs via the web service that you have to build according to Apple's spec.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still few questions rise:
1. Right now I am getting pass from api and just performing add to wallet through my app. But, you said you have to create pass if you want to be able to update it. But I need to get the pass updated from backend only because only backend can update data dynamically once app gets live

Comment: 2. Your app doesn't have much to do - just getting a pass (maybe from sone internal API of yours), and handing it over to the system.- Agreed

Comment: 3. Adding pass to wallet through my iOS app so, who will receive push token in call back my iOS app or webserver?

Comment: 4. My understanding from your answer says this web service will be called from backend only not from app side - am I correct?

Comment: After adding a pass, Apple will call the web service endpoints that start from the `webServiceUrl` property that you embedded in the pass when you made it, which will be on your server. Once you have the push token, you can send notifications to the device using it, but it targets the pass, not your app. Your app is not involved at all, and it's independent of any other notifications that you might send.

Comment: thanks, if you feel please vote for reopen this question as these doubts will be and can come in mind of many developers.